# replace a variable with formula in tradovate trading plateform

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modified a working stochastic oscillator on tradovate trading platform.  In formula of the stochastic there is the variable of close,  which I would like to replace with the result of another formula which variable name is vScore.  below is the complete working code of tradovate stochastic oscilallator then is the formula to get the vScore that I would like to replace the close variable. I have this working in thinkscript if these may help figure this out.

```
    const predef = require("../tools/predef");
    const meta = require("../tools/meta");
    const MovingHigh = require("../tools/MovingHigh");
    const MovingLow = require("../tools/MovingLow");
    const SMA = require("../tools/SMA");

    class stochastic {
        init() {
            this.highest = MovingHigh(this.props.period);
            this.lowest = MovingLow(this.props.period);
            this.sma = SMA(this.props.smoothPeriod);
           }

        map(d) {
            const high = d.high();
            const low = d.low();
            const close = d.close();
            const hh = this.highest(high);
            const ll = this.lowest(low);
            const K = (hh - ll) === 0 ? 0 : 100 * (close - ll) / (hh - ll);
            const D = this.sma(K);
            return {
                K,
                D
            };
        }


        filter(d) {
            return predef.filters.isNumber(d.D);
        }
    }

    module.exports = {
        name: "stochastic",
        title: "STO",
        description: "Stochastic Oscillator",
        calculator: stochastic,
        params: {
            period: predef.paramSpecs.period(14),
            smoothPeriod: predef.paramSpecs.period(3)
        },
        validate(obj) {
            if (obj.period < 1) {
                return meta.error("period", "Period should be a positive number");
            }
            if (obj.smoothPeriod < 2) {
                return meta.error("smoothPeriod", "Smooth period should be greater than 1");
            }
            return undefined;
        },
        inputType: meta.InputType.BARS,
        areaChoice: meta.AreaChoice.NEW,
        plots: {
            K: { title: "%K" },
            D: { title: "%D" }
        },
        tags: [predef.tags.Oscillators],
        schemeStyles: {
            dark: {
                K: predef.styles.plot("#CC33FF"),
                D: predef.styles.plot("#CC6600")
            }
        }
    };



    ////   formula to get the new value and additional tools that may be require for operation
    const StdDev = require("./tools/StdDev");
    const typicalPrice = require("./tools/typicalPrice");
    const p = require("./tools/plotting");
    const moment = require("moment");


    function vScore() {
         const volume = d.volume();
         const price = d.close();
         const vwp = (volume * price);
         const vwap = (vwp / volume);
         const vwapSQR = Math.sqrt(price - vwap)  * volume;
         const vwapSD = Math.sqrt(vwapSQR / volume);
         const vsc = ((price - vwap) / vwapSD);
         return vsc;
           }
```

I have tried placing the function prior to the class code and then calling for the variable, also inside the class and before the stochastic function but all attempt do not plot results.